# Why this solution is wrong?

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates

This is a question from LeetCode #217. Given an integer array `nums`, return `True` if any value appears at least twice in the array, and return `False` if every element is distinct.
And this is my code. I don't understand why it is wrong when the list has no duplicates?

```
class Solution:
     def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        nums.sort()
        b = False
        i = 0
        while i < len(nums) + 1:
            if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
                b = True
                return b
            else:
                b = False
        return b
```

Comment: `i` never gets updated. If `nums` is [1,2,3], it just keeps checking `nums[0]`.

Comment: What about just `len(nums) != len(set(nums))`?

Comment: Also the while condition will lead to checking num[i+1] out of bounds.

With a list of 5 elements, the while loop will be executed with i == 5, resulting in the if checking for nums[6] (out of bounds).

Comment: What do you return if only some elements are dupe?

Comment: Try to replace your returns in the while-loop with print. It is great for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that might help:

Increment the counter `i` after every `False` outcome (in your `else`
statement)

Have the system check until `len(nums)-1` (instead of
`len(nums)+1`) so that we avoid an `index out of range error` in the check `nums[i+1]`

```
def containsDuplicate(nums):
       nums.sort()
       b=False
       i=0
       while i<(len(nums)-1):
           if nums[i]==nums[i+1]:
               b=True
               return b
           else:
               b=False
               i += 1
       return b
```

### Results:

```
containsDuplicate([1, 2, 3])
False

containsDuplicate([1, 2, 2, 3])
True
```

### Alternate approaches:

This is also an alternate approach that is simpler and potentially easier to understand if you know that Python `set()` ([link to set documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)) cannot contain any duplicates. Thus converting the list `nums` to a set will remove duplicates automagically and then converting the set back to a list will allow you to compare the two lists. If they are NOT the same, then you know the original list had a duplicate:

```
def containsDuplicates(nums):
    return nums != list(set(nums))

containsDuplicates([1, 2, 3])
False

containsDuplicates([1, 2, 2, 3])
True
```

NOTE: the approach using the `set()` is substantially faster:

```
%%timeit
containsDuplicates(list(range(10000))+[9999])   # set version

306 µs ± 9.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
containsDuplicate(list(range(10000))+[9999]).   # sorted item-wise comparison

1.79 ms ± 13.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Why do you repeat the answer given before?

Comment: @SaeedEmamYari you and I were both writing our answers at the same time. I did not see your answer until after I submitted my answer. Apologies. I often draft quick answers and post them and then come back to edit them with more details so that future readers will have additional context.

Answer (score 0):

This approach prevents duplicative tests and do not require sorting

```
def contains_duplicate(nums: list) -> bool:
    for pos1, value in enumerate(nums):
        for pos2 in range(pos1+1, len(nums)):
            res = value + nums[pos2]
            if value == nums[pos2]:
                return True
    return False

print(contains_duplicate([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is wrong because:

- it causes out of bounds exceptions on good scenario input
- does't check for empty input and will cause an out of bound exception
- iterates incorrectly never updating the loop counter

Finally, it has design issues:

- side effects (sorts input w/o copying)
- useless code (b, setting it to either True or False in the loop even though False was default and True uses early return)
- wraps the solution into a useless class